# regex starting with number 5

Tags: python, regex

looking for help applying a regex function that finds a string that starts with 5 and is 7 digits long.

this is what i have so far based on my searches but doesn't work:

```
import re

string = "234324, 5604020, 45309, 45, 55, 5102903"
re.findall(r'^5[0-9]\d{5}', string)
```

not sure what i'm missing.

thanks

Comment: You are only matching from the start of the string, remove the `^` and you want to match 6 digits after the 5, not 5 digits.  You probably want to use word boundaries as well

Comment: Use http://regex101.com or similar sites to check/proof/test your regexes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a `^`, which asserts position at the start of the string.  Use a word boundary instead.  Also, you don't need both the `[0-9]` and the `\d`.

Use `\b5[0-9]{6}\b` (or `\b5\d{6}\b`) instead:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b5\d{6}\b', s)
['5604020', '5102903']
```

Answer (score 3):

The `^` at the start of the regular expression forbids any matches that aren't at the very beginning of the string. Replacing it with a negative lookbehind for `\d` to match non-digits or the beginning, and add a negative lookahead to forbid extra following digits:

```
import re

string = "234324, 5604020, 45309, 45, 55, 5102903"
re.findall(r'(?<!\d)5\d{6}(?!\d)', string)
```

Comment: This won't match a valid match at the beginning of a string.  Try it with `s = '5123456'`.  `\D` matches any character that isn't a digit, but beginning of the is not a character match, and `\D` doesn't check for zero length matches

Comment: You're right. I changed it to be negative lookbehind/ahead

Comment: This still will miss out if you have `s = 67.5678903`

Comment: @Onyambu A word boundary still matches the position where `.` meets `5` in `67.5678903`.

Comment: It's ambiguous if op wants to treat periods as number boundaries (if they are treated as separators) or if they are included as part of the number as decimal points.

Comment: then you will need a lookbehind with a space

Answer (score 1):

Try to match: Boundary `5` followed by  `6` digits and after that match non-digit character in a non-capturing group.

`\b5` looks `5` at start of numbers

`\d{6}` matches 6 digits
`(?:\D|$)` non-capturing group: ignores non-digit or `$`

```
\b5\d{6}(?:\D|$)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/EYZbK5/6)

```
import re

string = "234324, 5604020, 45309, 45, 55, 5102903"
re.findall(r'\b5\d{6}(?:\D|$)', string)
```

Comment: No, this will match `45123456` too. Use some boundaries. Also while you are matching `5\d{6}` which means `7` digits you don't have to repeat it inside a lookahead.

Comment: You can safely remove the lookahead.